# jQuery check which data-type exists?

Tags: jquery, html, jquery-mobile, radio-button, radio-group

Does anyone know how to test which data-type a fieldset has using jQuery Mobile?  I am attempting to change the background color of the label element for radio buttons that are positioned horizontally but only change the ui-icon background color of radio buttons that are positioned vertically.  Just can't figure out how to determine which type of radio button my code is looking at.

Any ideas would be greatly appreciated!

This is a sample to the html code block I am using to display horizontal radio buttons.

```
<div data-role="fieldcontain">
   <fieldset data-role="controlgroup" data-type="horizontal">
       <legend>* Are you a smoker?</legend> 
           <input type="radio" name="smoke" value="Yes" id="smokeY"/>
           <label for="smokeY" class="radioButton">Yes</label>

           <input type="radio" name="smoke" value="No" id="smokeN"/>
           <label for="smokeN" class="radioButton">No</label>
   </fieldset>
</div>
```

This is a sample of the html code block I am using to display vertical radio buttons

```
<div data-role="fieldcontain">
   <fieldset data-role="controlgroup">
       <legend>* Do you have a vehicle in good working order?</legend>          
           <input type="radio" name="car" value="Yes" id="carY"/>
            <label for="carY" class="radioButton">Yes</label>

            <input type="radio" name="car" value="No" id="carN"/>
            <label for="carN" class="radioButton">No</label>
   </fieldset>
</div>
```

Here is the halfway working jQuery I am using

```
for (group in radio_groups) {
if (!$(":radio[name=" + group + "]:checked").length) {
    isValid = false;
     $("input:radio[name=" + group + "]").each(function() {

    /// this code changes the icon background of vertical radio buttons
            $(this).next().find('.ui-icon').css('background-color', '#FF7575');

    //// i think i need some kind of if statement here that can identify if the radio button
    //// is horizontal or vertical

            $(this).next().css('background', '#FF7575');
    //// the above changes the lable background of horizontal radio buttons

      });
 } else {
      $("input:radio[name=" + group + "]").each(function() {
            $(this).next().find('.ui-icon').css('background-color', '#A7E9A7');
      });
 }
}
```

UPDATE:

[HERE IS MY WORKING JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ofwdwqxq/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To read a data attribute called `data-type` with jQuery Mobile, use the **[jqmData()](http://api.jquerymobile.com/jqmData/)** method:

```
$(selector).jqmData("type");
```

Test for "horizontal", as vertical is default and could be undefined.

> Here is a **[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/ezanker/7fxatzh6/)**

**UPDATE:**

As you iterate the radio buttons, you can see if they are horizontal or vertical by getting the controlgroup parent and checking its type:

```
$("input[type='radio']").each(function() {
    var cg = $(this).parents("fieldset:jqmData(role='controlgroup')");
    var IsHoriz = cg.jqmData("type") =='horizontal';
    if (IsHoriz){
        alert('horiz');
    } else {
        alert('vert');
    }
});
```

> Updated **[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/ezanker/7fxatzh6/2/)**

Comment: I like this....do you know how I would put it all together to make my existing code work with your suggestion?

Comment: @Austin, also here is your updated fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/ezanker/ofwdwqxq/2/

Answer (score 0):

You can accomplish this with just CSS...no need for any Javascript at all. It will execute faster and is less code to maintain!

```
fieldset input[type="radio"] { ... } // unchecked vertical radio
fieldset input[type="radio"]+label { ... } // label immediately after unchecked vertical radio
fieldset input[type="radio"]:checked { ... } // checked vertical radio
fieldset input[type="radio"]:checked+label { ... } // label immediately after checked vertical radio

fieldset[data-type="horizontal"] input[type="radio"] { ... } // unchecked horizontal radio
fieldset[data-type="horizontal"] input[type="radio"]+label { ... } // label immediately after horizontal radio
fieldset[data-type="horizontal"] input[type="radio"]:checked { ... } // checked horizontal radio
fieldset[data-type="horizontal"] input[type="radio"]:checked+label { ... } // label immediately following checked horizontal radio
```

You might even want to check out [SASS](http://sass-lang.com/) to make this even simpler to write.

Comment: Would there be a way to use your example with my jQuery?  I love your code but not to sure how to make it dynamic so only certain buttons are changed vs all of them.

Comment: Absolutely, you just have to adjust the CSS selectors. You can target the individual 'name' attribute of each radio button like this `input[name="car"]` for individual buttons, or simply add a class if you want to make changes to more than one button like this `input.className`

Comment: One other point of clarification: By using jQuery to handle this, you have to run your for loop on each click the user makes, right? That's a lot of unneccessary computation if they click around a lot or if there are many radio button groups in your form. Now, when you're validating your form for submission you absolutely what to use a for loop like this to add an error message to the screen.